# Replace string use regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have this string.

```
string str = "5595176&cn=ANY&ln=ADdedfr";
```

I need to replace ANY to 12345

```
string str = "5595176&cn=12345&ln=ADdedfr
```

string ANY may be different.

Comment: I wan't to replace any, any can be different..? Is it always prefixed by cn=? And do you have to use ragex? Why not split and replace or something. Also does any always have the same length? How do we know what to replace if it can be different.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava But any can be different it says, that's why you need more information :) but regex doesn't sound necessary here though.

Comment: I have JS solution))  Please look at

Comment: link = link.replaceAll("cn=[A-Za-z]+", "cn=" + countryCode);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string mystr = Regex.Replace(str, "cn=[A-Za-z]+", "cn=12345");
```

According to the comment it could be

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string mystr = Regex.Replace(str, "cn=[A-Za-z]+", "cn=" + CountryCode);
```

Comment: Thankyou. Good. Worked)

Comment: Happy to help. :) @IgorStrekha Happy Coding Kudos. :)